# conversion of String to Image android

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<String> arl =(ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("WordList");
```

I want a string stored in this array to be converted into image and display the same in the imageview. Anybody suggest how to implement it.

Comment: I think a little bit more background would help. *Why* are you trying to create an image out of text?

Comment: I want to display some text in random place and use the option of drag and drop to change its position. These text are being received from another activity where it is created dynamically.

Comment: So you don't want to create an image?  You want to set the text to a TextView and to be able to drag the TextView?

Comment: yes i want to drag the text which is stored in arraylist.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom view.  Override the view's onDraw(Canvas canvas) method and draw the text.

(semi-pseudo code):

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
      canvas.drawText(textToDraw);
}
```